# Display ListView items in a row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am having a hard time figuring out how to get my FilterChips in a row.
I would like to display all FilterChips per category in a row and not in a seperated column.
Tried different approaches but non of them seems to work.

Hopefully someone can help me with this, thanks for help!

Here is my code:

```
    Widget _buildListView(List<Category> categories) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: categories.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return _buildSection(categories[index]);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSection(Category category) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          category.title,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        ),
// How can I get my FilterChips side by side?
        Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: category.interests.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Interest interest = category.interests[index];
                    return FilterChip(label: Text(interest.interest), onSelected: (isSelected){
                      selectedInterests.add(interest.id);
                    });
                    return Text(interest.interest);
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: categories,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Category> categories = snapshot.data;
            return _buildListView(categories);
          }

          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class StackOver extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 60,
          left: 10.0,
          right: 10.0,
        ),
        child: Wrap(
          children: List.generate(
            10,
            (index) {
              return FilterChip(
                label: Text('index $index'),
                onSelected: (val) {},
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: With scrollDirection I get errors like this: 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.

Comment: Hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54774024/constraints-hasboundedheight-is-not-true-flutter

Comment: You need the `FilterChip` to be able to scroll horizontally if I understood your question? There is no need to wrap in a `Row` and `Flexible` widget then.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Actually I dont want the FilterChips to be scrollable, just grouped together in a row. Is the ListView the wrong Widget for that purpose?

Comment: If you don't want the FilterChips to be scrollable, you shouldn't use a ListView then. The `Wrap` widget is what you need.

Comment: Super, thank you very much! I combined it with [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441168/iterating-through-a-list-to-render-multiple-widgets-in-flutter/50451020) to iterate over the list.